# how to get class of a dragged item after been received by the target sortable?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, drag-and-drop

```
 $(".target").droppable({
                connectWith: ".connected",
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var targetId = event.target.id;//--> id of the target (where elements will be dropped into)
                    var orderId;//--> id of the dragged element (NOT the targetId)

                    if ($(this).hasClass("source connected")) {
                        orderId = sourceElementSo;
                    }
                    else {
                        orderId = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
                    };
```

i've tried ui.item and ui.draggable, but no success

PS: Newbie :)

Comment: $(this).hasClass("source connected")

Comment: Thx @VladuIonut, but still not working!

Comment: can you provide more details or a fiddle with the code ?

Comment: i've edited my entry

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    connectWith: ".connected",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {  
       var targetId = event.target.id;//--> id of the target (where elements will be dropped into)
                    var orderId;//--> id of the dragged element (NOT the targetId)

                    if (ui.draggable.hasClass("connected")) {
                       console.log("ok");
                        orderId = sourceElementSo;
                    }
                    else {
                        orderId = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
                    };
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
  #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
  #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content connected">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>
 
<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```